# XCOPY crashing when I try to copy and rename 80K files. Is there a better way?

Tags: windows, copy, robocopy, xcopy

Probably there is a better approach to fix what I am trying to do. I have a folder with pictures that I want to copy to another folder renaming them.

Basically, I have a list of all the 80K files of the file name they have, and what is the new name that they should have. There is no fixed pattern to rename the files. What I’ve been doing is using Excel to find the path and current file name and then renaming the files checking the new file name in a SQL database.

Basically, for every file I form a XCOPY line then I paste them on powershell.

echo F|xcopy /s /q /y /f "file path" "renamed file path"

My problem is that for some reason powershell stops processing the xcopy lines after approximately 4K files. I already tried running this as a BAT with these lines for each file.

xcopy /s /q /y /f "file path" "renamed file path *" with an asterisk at end to avoid the question if it’s a file or a folder. But it stops processing after 2K files.

I know that robocopy is better than xcopy but I need to rename each file, and there is not a clear pattern in the renaming, I don’t know how to do a robocopy each file and then rename each file, but that should be even worse no?

Also, the server has a good SSD and its only processing 1 xcopy line per each second, should be a lot faster. The .jpg files are small (˜200Kb).

Any ideas are appreciated.

Regards,
Tiago